# Uncaught ReferenceError: y (var) is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

that's a real quick problem that I want to share with you all.. I'm not sure why.. but Chrome and Opera - I haven't tested on Firefox - just don't want to assume the value of my var (y), and it just doesn't happen on Edge and Explorer..

The objetive o the code is depending of the option o select the var y get a diferente value and consequently the var Uf too..

I started studying JavaScript a week ago.. so I'm really sorry for bothering you all! :)

```js
function uf(x){   
  if ( x == null) { y = 1;}
  if ( x == 1 ) { y = 1200; }
  if ( x == 2 ) { y = 1550; }
  if ( x == 3 ) { y = 1500; }
  if ( x == 4 ) { y = 1550; }

  var Uf = y;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select required>
    <option onclick="uf(null)">UF</option>
    <option onclick="uf(1)">RS</option>
    <option onclick="uf(2)">RJ</option>
    <option onclick="uf(3)">SP</option>
    <option onclick="uf(4)">MG</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

### ERROR

Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined

at uf (JS.js:19)

at HTMLInputElement.onclick (Index.html:88)

Comment: You can't use events on `<option>` . They are not supported in some browsers. Use `onchange` on `<select>`

Comment: But then the function won't lose its purpose?

Comment: Define `y` outside of all the if statements. `y` is scope variable inside if statements and you are trying to use it outside.eg:`function uf(x){   
 let y = 0;  if ( x == null) { y = 1;}....`

Comment: @Kavindra OP is actually using `y` as a global variable due to there being no `var y`. This won't work in strict mode but `y` is definitely **not** scoped to the `if` statement

Comment: @L.Bravo your error message does not match your markup. You have no `HTMLInputElement` instances. Your function is also brittle; why not just pass the _y_ value in as the argument, ie `uf(1)`, `uf(1200)`, etc?

Comment: That was, actually, my first thought, but didn't work

Comment: @Phill 'Cause the code is larger.. and I use this same function to define other things..

Answer (score 0):

```
function uf(x){   
var y;
if ( x == null) { y = 1;}
if ( x == 1 ) { y = 1200; }
if ( x == 2 ) { y = 1550; }
if ( x == 3 ) { y = 1500; }
if ( x == 4 ) { y = 1550; }

var Uf = y;
}
```

Comment: try using value onchange instead of onclik, since select is basically using onchange, verify value at every <select id = "mys"> <option value = "val2"> .... </ option> </ select>
then get value with onchange so you can get value from each change select
//mys.onchange=function () {}

Comment: Like create a var for the select  `var x = document.getElementById("selectID")` and than create a function for it `x.onchange = function()` where `if ( x.value == "null" ) { y = 1 }` and `Uf = y`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

### HTML

```
   <div>
      <select id="selection" required>
        <option value="value1">UF</option>
        <option value="value2">RS</option>
        <option value="value3">RJ</option>
        <option value="value4">SP</option>
        <option value="value5">MG</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var y = document.getElementById("selection").value;

var Uf = y;
```

Thanks for the help guys!